# Can JavaFx scenebuilder used to create Java Code instead of FXML

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm a beginner in Javafx. I found that `Javafx Scene builder` is pretty cool to generate any forms related to Javafx, but it does play with only `fxml` files and not with `java` files.

For e.g: When I create `MenuList`, `Items` etc. using Scene Builder it just generates the source with similar html files only (XML output).

But I do not want to `confine with the use of these XML files`. So does anyone knows the individual technique to handle along `java file` without using `fxml` ?

Comment: For netbeans users, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661242/tool-to-convert-fxml-to-java-code/42480616#42480616..

Answer (score 4):

*The answer to your question* **Can JavaFx scenebuilder used to create Java Code instead of FXML** is **You Can't**

If you need to use *Java to create your Presentation Layer, you will have to do it by writing codes on your own and there are reasons to it*. Please follow the post below :

*JavaFX empowers you to create UI using both Java code and XML-based language called `FXML`*. Scene Builder was introduced to leverage the use of FXML, by providing a `DRAG n DROP` feature, to generate FXML code. You can consider this similar to [Window Builder for Swing](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/), with a difference of the end result being in FXML(.fxml) instead of Java(.java).

**Basic Difference b/w Java code and FXML**

***Java Code***

```
BorderPane border = new BorderPane();
Label toppanetext = new Label("Page Title");
border.setTop(toppanetext);
Label centerpanetext = new Label ("Some data here");
border.setCenter(centerpanetext);
```

***FXML***

```
<BorderPane>
    <top>
        <Label text="Page Title"/>
    </top>
    <center>
        <Label text="Some data here"/>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

**Why Use FXML, When I can achive the same via JAVA code**

You would be thinking as to why to use FXML, when we can make the same using `JAVA`. Well, its your choice !!

***From the docs***

> FXML is an XML-based language that provides the structure for building
>   a user interface separate from the application logic of your code.
>   This separation of the presentation and application logic is
>   attractive to web developers because they can assemble a user
>   interface that leverages Java components without mastering the code
>   for fetching and filling in the data

So, FXML forces you to use a MVC pattern, keeping your presentation layer separate from the logic, making it easier for you to maintain and edit the presentation layer, and through UI designers, who have no relation to Java/JavaFX

[For more information and example on FXML](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/why_use_fxml.htm#CHDCHIBE)

Comment: Hmmm,
I when I programmed in SWT I used a technology called XWT which allowed me to create GUIS with xmls. It was pretty horrible. Bindings didn't work, focus was stolen, and scroll bar didn't want to be added.

Is FXML any better? I am traumotized by XWT and I now I don't want to program in FXML.

Answer (score 2):

SceneBuilder is for the creation of the gui visually via fxml and does not generate any java code at all. This is left up to the developer.

A good starting tutorial is here: http://code.makery.ch/java/javafx-2-tutorial-part1/

It goes over the use of JavaFX with Eclipse and SceneBuilder

Comment: Have a look into this [pic](http://postimg.org/image/c6udm0azn/) pls.. I want to generate this codes.. using Scene builder.. Is that possible?